# Is it possible to declare global array of type String[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

What i wanted do is this:

```
class test{
public static String[][] p;

}
```

But something is wrong.
When i try to write sth to it by using:

```
p[][]={...};
```

It says: "p cannot be resolved to a type".

EDIT:
Ok, I see there were some problems with understanding what i am talking about so i post a code here.

```
public class Test{
    static String[][] plansza;
    public static void main(String []arg){

                p[][]={ {"  ","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"},
                  {"1.","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"},
                  {"2.","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0"},
                  {"3.","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"},
                  {"4.","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
                  {"5.","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
                  {"6.","2","0","2","0","2","0","2","0"},
                  {"7.","0","2","0","2","0","2","0","2"},
                  {"8.","2","0","2","0","2","0","2","0"}
                  };
       }
```

Comment: That's not how you "write something to it". Refer to a [basic tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Maybe try `p = new String[][]{{...},{...}};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like the follwoing

```
public class Test{
static String[][] plansza;
public static void main(String []arg){

            plansza = new String[][] { {"  ","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"},
              {"1.","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"},
              {"2.","1","0","1","0","1","0","1","0"},
              {"3.","0","1","0","1","0","1","0","1"},
              {"4.","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
              {"5.","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"},
              {"6.","2","0","2","0","2","0","2","0"},
              {"7.","0","2","0","2","0","2","0","2"},
              {"8.","2","0","2","0","2","0","2","0"}
              };
   }
}
```

you must place `new String[][]{....};` before assign it to plansza

Answer (score 1):

To create array normally you need to at least set first dimension of array, but normally you do it like

1) `new Type[dim1][dim2]..[dimN]`

You can skip dimensions if you initialize arrays with elements like

2) `new Type[][]..[]{{..{elements},},..}}`

But if you are initializing your array with elements ***in the same place where you are declaring it*** then you can skip `new Type[][]...[]` part and just use `{{..{elements},},..}}` like

3) `Type[][]..[] myArray = {{..{elements},},..}}`

---

In your case you are having case 2) because you are not initializing your array in place you declared it. So instead of

```
p[][] = {
  {"  ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"},
  ...
  };
```

you need to write it as

```
p = new String[][]{
  {"  ","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"},
  ...
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of initialization:

```
public static String[][] s = new String[][]{
    {"A", "B", "C"},
    {"D", "E", "F"}
};
```

This would define dinamically your `multidimensional Array`

Answer (score 0):

You can only use array constants in initializers.

Therefore:

```
// will compile
public static String[][] p = {{"foo", "bar"}};

// will compile
public static String[][] p;
static {
    p = new String[][]{{"foo", "bar"}};
}

// won't compile
public static String[][] p;
static {
    p = {{"foo", "bar"}};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand that `p` is a variable of type `String[][]` , thus initialize it in the following way

```
p = new String[][]{...};
```

In the above code `p` which is of type `String[][]` is assigned to an object initialized of the same type.

when you try to assign values, you can specify the indices like this

```
p[i][j] = "value";
```